# Convert values in column of lists of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have `df_test` below, with `col` containing a list of dictionaries as each row. How can I convert all of the values of `X` to `str`?

```py
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'col': [[{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}], [{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}, {'X': 1}], [{'X': 1}]]})
```

df_test:

```
    col
0   [{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}]
1   [{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}, {'X': 1}]
2   [{'X': 1}]
```

The original data contains `X` values of type `bson.objectid.ObjectId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the key (`'X'`) to its `str`:

```
>>> df_test.col.apply(lambda x: [{str(k): v for k, v in d.items()} for d in x])
0              [{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}]
1    [{'X': 1}, {'X': 1}, {'X': 1}]
2                        [{'X': 1}]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

To change the value (`1`) to its `str`:

```
>>> df_test.col.apply(lambda x: [{k: str(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in x])
0                [{'X': '1'}, {'X': '1'}]
1    [{'X': '1'}, {'X': '1'}, {'X': '1'}]
2                            [{'X': '1'}]
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_test['col'] = [str(key) for key in dict for dict in df_test['col']]
```